# Compile a Rust binary only for use in the crate's integration tests

Tags: testing, rust, integration-testing

I'm creating a standalone helper utility for use by some of my integration tests. I could write it in a scripting language like Bash or Python, but it would be convenient if it was a Rust binary since that's what the rest of the project is written in and would avoid complicating the project's testing dependencies. However I'm unsure if there's a good way to create a "test-only" binary. I know I could drop something into `bin/`, but it really shouldn't be used outside of tests so that seems like the wrong location (not to mention it would be compiled even when not needed).

Is there any way to define a binary that's only supposed to be compiled for testing? Sort of like the `dev-dependencies` config but for a binary rather than a dependency. I tried to see if a `tests/bin/` directory would work for example, but it didn't appear to get picked up when running `cargo test`.

Comment: Why isn't the utility code simply included in the integration tests? Is this utility meant to be used across projects? If so, I would make it as a separate library crate, so you can import and invoke it as a normal dependency. [Cargo does not currently support binary dependencies](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9096).

Comment: The utility is intentionally a separate process the tests will execute.

Comment: But the integration test could still fork and run the utility code in the child process... all from within a single crate.

Comment: Ok so you're suggesting forking in the integration test itself would be a better approach than just having a simple self-contained binary the test executes?

Comment: It's just a question of the extent to which you want to restrict this binary to the integration tests.  You could for example have a separate binary, provided by a separate package (perhaps within the same Cargo workspace); however you would then need to ensure that the binary is compiled and located suitably for launch by your integration tests—this is not something that `cargo test` will do for you.

Comment: Basically I just don't want the binary to be a public artifact of the project. It only exists for testing so it shouldn't be built by `cargo build` but `cargo build --tests` would compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the crate [Rust Test Binary](https://crates.io/crates/test-binary) to do this exact thing:

> If you have integration tests for things that involve subprocess management, inter-process communication, or platform tools, you might need to write some mock binaries of your own to test against. And if you're already using Cargo to build and test, it would be nice to be able to write those test binaries in Rust, near to the crate you're testing, as cargo projects themselves.
>
> This crate provides a simple interface for invoking Cargo to build test binaries organised in a separate directory under your crate.

Note that you might be able to get away with using a binary in `examples`, which can be simpler. But my crate is for situations where you need different dependencies, features, or generally want some insulation between your "mock" program compilation and your integration tests.